# Using Qiskit with Blender

Tags: qiskit, nonlocal-games

I want to use Blender and Blender Python Scripts working with Qiskit.
(want to make 3D creations) (www.blender.org)

How can I do this ?
(because when I try to install Qiskit inside Blender Python, it doesn't work )

How to make communication between Blender and Qiskit installed with Anaconda Python ?

Thanks

Alain

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
sys.exec_prefix
```

will show the path of python used by blender. Rename this `python` folder to something else. Now blender will automatically use the python version in windows path. Make sure that your Python runs in command prompt when you type `python`. If it doesn't, type `environment variables` in search and add python.exe to the path variable. Restart command prompt if `python` opens up python interpreter, blender will too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Qiskit from within a conda virtual environment? If Blender isn't launched from within the same venv they may not be able to communicate (or share libraries).